# Add fake data to a data frame based on variable condition

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

Good afternoon,

I have to add dummy data to a dataframe whenever a specific variable is absent of several given intervals.

```
require(plyr)
df <- data.frame(length = c(1.5e+07, 2.5e+07), grade = c(1000, 1000), company = "TEST")
for(x in df$length){
if (x<=0|x>1e+07) {
df <- rbind.fill(df, data.frame(length = c(5000000), grade = c(1000)))
}
```

This works fine but I am having trouble to check if x is absent in each “length” interval from 0 to 1e+08, with a step of 1e+07, and add  “1000“ in “grade” if that is the case. I tried all lot of things, and the end my data frame is only 1 row larger.

After that, I will create subgroups based on these intervals and I need a value for each subgroup.

```
df$length <- cut(df$length, breaks = seq(0, 1e+08, 1e+07))
```

In the end, the objective is to still get an empty space on a boxplot for each condition where there is no data, as the “1000“ I added is way above the limit threshold. 
The next step will be to do the same but for each “company” variable.

I hope I am clear, sorry for my English.

Thanks

Comment: We can't guess what `...` is supposed to mean. You should post the full code, or at least close the brackets so we know that's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By "..." I meant that I do not know how to continue this code, so I tried to explain my problem in the following paragraph. I corrected by adding the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

First, cut your df$length:

```
df <- data.frame(length = c(1.5e+07, 2.5e+07), grade = c(1000, 1000), company = "TEST")
df$length <- cut(df$length, breaks = seq(0, 1e+08, 1e+07))
```

Now we can use dplyr to `left_join` on all the levels of `length`, we then `complete` company:length, filter out any NA companies, and  change the NA to 1000:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% left_join(data.frame(length = levels(df$length)), .) %>%
       complete(length, company) %>%
       filter(!is.na(company)) %>%
       mutate(grade = ifelse(is.na(grade), 1000, grade)) 

Source: local data frame [10 x 3]

          length company grade
          (fctr)  (fctr) (dbl)
1      (0,1e+07]    TEST  1000
2  (1e+07,2e+07]    TEST  1000
3  (2e+07,3e+07]    TEST  1000
4  (3e+07,4e+07]    TEST  1000
5  (4e+07,5e+07]    TEST  1000
6  (5e+07,6e+07]    TEST  1000
7  (6e+07,7e+07]    TEST  1000
8  (7e+07,8e+07]    TEST  1000
9  (8e+07,9e+07]    TEST  1000
10 (9e+07,1e+08]    TEST  1000
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have to wait until I am able to DL dplyr and tidyr, but I feel that it will work. I made mistakes however, for my df the "grade" values are different than "1000" (between -5 and 5), but it looks like it will not matter.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what is happening. However, I would like to add these values to the original df, not "only" to display them in a new data frame. If I try df %>% left_join(data.frame(length = levels(df$length)), .) %>%
       complete(length, company) %>%
       filter(!is.na(company)) %>%
       mutate(grade = ifelse(is.na(grade), 1000, grade))

Comment: it will add them on - try it on eg : `df <- data.frame(length = c(1.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 1234), grade = c(12, 10, 55), company = c("TEST", "TEST2", "test23")); df$length <- cut(df$length, breaks = seq(0, 1e+08, 1e+07))`

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! I will validate your answer. By the way my "real" data frame as few more columns that I do not need to modify or add values, but I think I should still add them somewhere in this script. Should I only modify the dataframe, and the complete() arguments ? Again thank you

Comment: at the moment, the extra columns will have NA if there was no value previously. If you want to have something else, take a look at the `fill` argument in `?complete`

Comment: Thank you, I will look at the ?complete description. If I want additionally each company to have these dummy data (if needed) for each interval, should I use a for loop plus this script ? I've been struggling for days ...